# Resize div to fit content and center align in parent using fxLayout

Tags: html, angular, css

[image]

How do I achieve the layout as per the image above using fxLayout in Angular?

here is a sample of my code and an image of the result. My red div defaults to the width of the blue div and the items align to the left leaving padding on the right which makes the result off center.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <div class="blue" fxFlex="80%" fxLayout="row">
        <div class="red" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <app-item *ngFor="let item of items.all" [item]="item"></app-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: From the test I have done, it is fxLayoutWrap that is causing the issues. Is there another way of wrapping the items?

Answer (score 0):

I am exploring another option for anyone that is interested.
https://brianflove.com/2017/05/03/responsive-angular/

Answer (score 0):

I happened to came across the same problem as well recently as I've just started using `@angular/flex-layout` recently. It is the `fxLayoutWrap` that is causing the problem. I'm unsure if you have found the answer since this post has been for some time. You will need to specify it as `fxLayout="row wrap"` instead of `fxLayoutWrap` since it has been removed.